# Implementing State Machine for Unity3D NPC characters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state-machine

I can't seem to wrap my head around this topic and i need a bit of a push forward, maybe an example.

I'm currently developing a project including simulating a large number of automated characters trying to fulfill their "needs".
As for now the characters have their need levels stored in their scripts as simple floating point <0,1> value and check every frame if it exceeds a given value and then try to move to a defined point and satisfy their need.

The problem is one character can have many needs and that leads to a situation when an character moves to satisfy one need and it drops just below the threshold it moves to satisfy the next need. Assuming that later i would like the needs to "rise" over time this will be a big problem.

I **think** i should implement an state machine to transition from idle -> move to satisfy -> wait to satisfy -> idle but as i said i cant quite understand the whole state machine thing. The closest to understanding for me was this: https://github.com/nblumhardt/stateless but I still cant wrap my mind around it.

Would be grateful for any help, tutorials, examples, anything.

Comment: What i can suggest to is, draw it somewhere first. List your states. Preferably on a piece of paper. Keep it simple at first. Somethink like [this](http://martindevans.me/assets/FiniteStateMachine.png)  Then decide what will make your states to change. Ex: Character is sitting, character is hungry, character go eat, character return to sit. You already have a value for those needs so when it reaches that value change to that state. In short; vizualize it first!

Comment: If you have many diffferent needs you could maybe enumerate needs that are below the line, finally deciding to resolve that one which is most critical first. Like: idle -> check for needs -> resolve most critical -> repeat